# Websphere on Eclipse 4.19.0

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, war

I need to run a .war on websphere.
In my eclipse, in servers i have Tomcat and others, but not Websphere.
When I go to market place in eclipse, I search for IBM Websphere and I receive an error message saying i can't be installed on that eclipse version.

How can I deploy a websphere server in eclipse 4.19.0?

Thanks

edit: error message says:
No repository found at https://public.dhe.ibm.com/install_not_applicable_for_this_version_of_eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebSphere Developer Tools for WebSphere traditional do not run on Java SE 11 which is required by Eclipse 4.19. You have to use Eclipse 4.16 or earlier.

The WebSphere Developer Tools for Liberty do run on Java SE 11 so can be used on 4.19. There are lots of people using Liberty as a development environment for applications that will run on WebSphere traditional, but it does depend on what your application does.